# UI5 Ajax - same origin - Issue [UI5]

Tags: node.js, ajax, sapui5

I have an application that uses `ui5` for the frontend and `node.js` for the backend.

When trying to access a ressource via `ajax`, i do get the same origin issue due to frontend being at `localhost:8080` while the (backend) ressource is at `localhost:3000/SixWonders`.

**Questions:**

Should the server domain be renamed and the ressource placed at `localhost:8080/SixWonders` ?
If so, there is a conflict of either the files of `ui5` or that of `node.js` being at localhost:8080.

How do i solve this issue ?

Comment: It depends... how will the app (front and backend) be deployed?

Comment: @Marc i am not familiar with deployment, the app at hand is developed localy. However the app at work, does share the same url for backend and frontend.

Comment: Then you could enable CORS in your backend IFF it is running in a dev env. Or start some kind of npm http proxy which redirects localhost:3000/sixwonders to localhost:8080/sixwonders